# Read a local file in firefox using fileAPI

Tags: javascript, html, browser, fileapi

I have a use-case in which a local web page(with out server) needs to read files in current directory and show its content.

My question here is :
  Is is possible to do so? if possible , how? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no, it isn't. The File API allows access to files selected with a file input.

If you want to read data from other files with files stored on the local hard drive, your best best is to encode the data in those files as JSONP and load it by generating script elements (as is usual for JSONP).